# How can I use Fortify only for 2FA in Laravel with Passport?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, fortify, two-factor-authentication

I have a Laravel 9 project and I use Passport for the authentication cycle. I don't use views because the frontend is developed in Vue.

Now I should include 2FA and I found Fortify in Laravel documentation. It seems simple to use, but when I make a request to a Fortify endpoint the response is:

> Session store not set on request

This is my fortify.php file

```
//other code

'guard' => 'api',

//other code

'home' => '',

//other code

'views' => false, //I don't need Fortify views, I'll use only consuming API

//other code

'features' => [
    Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
        'confirmPassword' => true
    ]),
],

//other code
```

When I set `confirmPassword` to false the request response is 200 and 2FA fields in DB are filled (I haven't tested yet the complete cycle because I need confirm password, so I want to solve this problem first of all).

So, to quickly summarize: I use Passport for auth in Laravel 9. I need Fortify for 2FA without its views, only by consuming API. What could cause that error?